# How to write a d.ts declaration file to import a default class and a named export in typescript?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, node-modules, typescript-typings, es6-modules

I have a javascript library that has the following module that I would like to import in typescript:

```
export {  
  namedFunction
};

export default DefaultClass;
```

I do import it like that in typescript and it works:

```
import DefaultClass, {
  namedFunction
} from 'myModule';
```

All this works, but now I want to add a declaration file to not just use `any`. And I am completely stuck as it seems `export default class` just does not work. What I managed to get is this:

```
declare module 'myModule';
declare module 'myModule' {
    class DefaultClass {
    }

    export = DefaultClass;

    namespace DefaultClass {

    }
}
```

With that I can import my class and my namedFunction, but I cannot figure a way to add typings to the namedFunction. I don't even understand why do we need an empty namespace for this to work, without it typescript complains.

Is there a way to add typings to all of my classes/functions?

P.S. Note this is not a typo with double declaration. It does not allow me to specify namedFunction, but at least allows it to be imported as any, don't really know why...

Comment: Remove the wrapper and just write `export declare function... ` and `export declare default class... ` put the Declaration file beside the JS file

Comment: I cannot change the javascript file, it's in a library that I use. I have tried to export like you suggest, but it does not quite work for me. If I export just the namedFunction e.g. I get this: `A declare modifier cannot be used in an already ambient context`

Comment: So it is a third party package you are typing? Our approach will be slightly different then

Comment: Yes, it's a third party package that I am trying to add typings to